# ruby scan method: What does ^ do?

Tags: ruby, regex

I wrote a method to print EUR prices:

```
print((" " + text).scan(/\d+,\d+ EUR/).map {|m| m.reverse.chop.reverse})
```

by

```
text = "this is 14,67 EUR"
```

it works for all digits after the comma, but is missing the first digit (returns 4,67 instead of 14,67)

I found a line to solve my problem:

```
text.scan(/[^\d]\d,\d+ EUR/)
```

But why is this working and what does the ^ do?

Comment: "this is 14,67 EUR".scan(/\d+,\d+ EUR/) seems to produce the desired result?

Comment: I belive you need `text.scan(/(?<!\d)\d,\d+ EUR\b/)`, if you need to match `1,234 EUR` like input and not match `12,4556 EUR`

Comment: At least in Ruby world its called a "Hat". Try some Regex exercises

Answer (score 2):

- `^` when first inside the brackets is the "not" operator
- `/[^\d]/` means not a digit

---

```
text.scan(/[^\d]\d,\d+ EUR/)
```

Says:

- look for a non-digit
- followed by one digit
- followed by a comma
- followed by one or more digits
- followed by a space
- followed by "EUR"